# What is `oahd-helper` and why is it eating my CPU?

Tags: macos, monterey, activity-monitor, rosetta, rosetta-2

I noticed today that when changing SIP mode (either enabling or disabling), upon reboot my macOS Monterey CPU usage is heavily consumed by a series of `oahd` and `oahd-helper` processes.

Researching reveals (see [eclecticlight.co](https://eclecticlight.co/2021/01/22/running-intel-code-on-your-m1-mac-rosetta-2-and-oah/) and [ProjectChampollion GitHub](https://ffri.github.io/ProjectChampollion/part1/) ) this to be related to Rosetta2/AOT but there isn't much detail about what it's doing or how to tame it.

If left alone, eventually things settle down after about ***17 minutes*** of churning.

Here are some screenshots from my M1 Mac Mini system, running 12.5 as of this writing:

[image]
[image]

How can I manage this better?

Comment: How often do you need to change SIP mode?

Comment: Is not installing Rosetta an option? That’s the best way to avoid the traffic by opting out cleanly.

Answer (score 11):

This `oahd-helper` is the ahead of time compiler for Rosetta. Essentially what you are doing is causing it to scan a large volume of programs and compile / cache the translated code for Rosetta to run when an intel program is invoked.

Twenty minutes to do all the work seems reasonable - even if it took double you would be in the normal range for my experience.

Other than not triggering this, your only option is a third party app like https://stclairsoft.com/AppTamer/index.html

1. Delete intel code from the system to reduce the potential workload
2. Trigger this fewer or better managed times *(perhaps where you are about to take a break and let cpu use settle while you are afk)*
3. See if App Tamer can let you delay the process if you want it to take longer to complete with a flatter CPU use profile